# SPSS: how to calculate nearest neighbor from k-means centroids

Tags: cross-validation, spss, k-means, k-nearest-neighbour, hierarchical-clustering

the subject of my problem is related to cluster analysis. Specifically, with SPSS I am conducting a cross-validation procedure based on splitting the sample data into two independent halves (subsample 1 and subsample 2) of an original sample of cases.

In the first half (subsample 1), I performed a hierarchical cluster analysis (in particular, I adopted Ward's method) to identify the number of clusters and I saved the centroids of my solution; then, on the same sample of data, I used the centroids identified with the hierarchical mode as starting points/initial seeds to perform a k-means analysis. Finally, I saved the centroids obtained with k-means.
In the second half (subsample 2) I would need to use the centroids found via k-means to classify the cases/subjects using the nearest neighbour technique but I don't know to do that.

Does anyone know how to do a classification in SPSS in which the nearest neighbour technique reads the k-means centroids to classify the data (thus producing a new variable based on this new type of classification)?

Comment: What do you mean specifically by the "nearest neighbour technique"? Aren't you simply planning to dispose new objects over the existing cluster centroids, to assign new objects to the centroids, to the respective nearest ones?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what you said. I tried following this path in SPSS: analyze --> classify --> k-means --> read initial (where there are the centroids I found via k-means made earlier) and also I selected the function "classify only" and specified the number of clusters. However, I do not know if this is the procedure

Comment: Yes, the "classify only" is the procedure. It only assigns points once to the input or to the initial centres, and stops. It does not iterate.

Comment: When you input the centres as a file or dataset, the number of clusters you request must coincide with the number of input centres.